# (curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1377)

Tags: ubuntu, curl, pipe

I am doing Kubernetes setup using the kubeadm in ubuntu (GCPO server) (i am following the steps based on the Kubernetes page but I am facing a  problem while running the command please find the command below
Command

sudo curl -fsSLo /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg  https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

Error message--

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1377)

I had browsed everything but I am not getting any results based on this please help me in this

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing k8s using kubeadm. I resolved it by running the following commands.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings/
sudo touch /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo curl -O https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
sudo cat apt-key.gpg > /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).